# vBulletin 4 Fetch thread permissions by external php-application

Tags: php, permissions, user-permissions, vbulletin, bit-fields

I am writing an addon to display the latest threads/posts of an vBulletin 4 forum in an extern application. Both systems are running on the same domain so that I'm able to get the vB session of the user in the external application. Because the vB forum has some forums with special permission (e.g. internal ones for staff) I want to show only threads which the user is at least allowed to read.

I found out that this can be done like the following:

```
$notAccessableForums = array();
foreach($vbulletin->forumcache as $forumId => $forumInfo) {
    // User need at least view-access
    $userCanViewForum = $vbulletin->userinfo['forumpermissions'][$forumId] & $vbulletin->bf_ugp_forumpermissions['canview'];
    if(!$userCanViewForum) {
        $notAccessableForums[] = $forumInfo['forumid'];
    }
}
```

`$notAccessableForums` will be an array of all forumIds which the current user can't access. This can be used easilly to exclude them in a SELECT statement for threads like

```
$query = 'SELECT title [...] 
FROM thread 
WHERE forumid NOT IN(' . implode(',', $notAccessableForums) . ');';
```

The problem with these solutions is that the vB core is needed for the forumlist and the forumpermissions of the user. I don't want to include the core because of the following reasons:

1. It makes my plugin unflexible because it need access to files of the vB board
2. When I include the vB-Core in my site it will slow down because there is already a CMS on it and the vBulletin-Core is really big which would resoult in bad performance
3. I want my plugin to be independence (as possible)

I took a look at the vB source code and found out that the forumpermissions are stored serialized in the `datastore` table (which is also a very huge array because there are also a lot of other information stored which I don't need like stats, relations and so on). But I couldn't figure out how I can get the user-specific permissions on a forum.

In other words: I need the bitfield which is stored in the vB var `$vbulletin->userinfo['forumpermissions'][$forumId]` so that I can define `$vbulletin->bf_ugp_forumpermissions['canview']` as constant in my class and get a list of all forums from the database to check which of them is not viewable by the current user.

Answer (score -1):

here is the complete article for vbulletin4 and VB5 latest post and comments for html and php sites

http://thearfan.com/vbulletin-latest-post-for-htmlphp-sites/

Comment: You did not even read the title of the question... Your plugin don't care about access-rights exactly like the vBulletin XML-API. Furthermore it's a HUGE mess: Bad coding-style, display database-errors to the users and breaking the WHOLE site for db-errors in a widget is at least not acceptable in production like using APIs which are deprecated for years and so on. Couldn't belive that this work is from a real software-engineer as asserted on your page. Looks like the first steps of a coder.

Comment: there is a config.php file where database setting needed.

Comment: 2nd the API that i am using is tested and i am using currently in for vb5.